# Open .txt file from same directory fails to find the file (FileNotFoundError) - python/kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want to open a few files for game in kivy (instructions, about info...), so I don't have to have everything typed in the main.py but using those two methods it gives me an error.

```
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    try:
        #os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
        #fullpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'navodila.txt')
        #instructions = StringProperty("")

        #with open(fullpath, "r") as inst:
        #    for line in inst:
        #        instructions += line

        instructions = ""
        with open("navodila.txt", "r") as file:
            for line in file:
                instructions += line

    except: instructions = "Instructions failed to load."

    def show_popup_inst(self):
        p = InstructionsPopup(content=Label(text=self.instructions, text_size=self.size))
        p.open()
```

They both give me the same FileNotFoundError. I've checked at least five times and the file is there.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Lara\Desktop\KIVY\LARA\Snaky Game\SNAKY REAL\SnakyGame4.py", line 361, in <module>
     class MenuScreen(Screen):
   File "C:\Users\Lara\Desktop\KIVY\LARA\Snaky Game\SNAKY REAL\SnakyGame4.py", line 371, in MenuScreen
     with open("navodila.txt", "r") as file:
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'navodila.txt'
```

The try, except part is there just because I was working on code after trying reading a file.

Am I using the methods wrong? I've tried writing both of them outside any of the classes but it gave me the same error so I returned it inside in MenuScreen class.

Comment: did you try running by giving it the full path

Comment: yes, isn't that the commented part? When I used that one, I commented the code below, but it gave me the same error

Comment: Is navodila.txt a symbolinc link? It could be broken.

Comment: No, the commented out part is you constructing some path. Try it with a literal full path. Also log the path you are trying to construct to see what you get.

Comment: your `.txt` files located in `C:\Users\Lara\Desktop\KIVY\LARA\Snaky Game\SNAKY REAL\ ` ? Try to explicitly specify the path to file: `open("C:\Users\Lara\Desktop\KIVY\LARA\Snaky Game\SNAKY REAL\navodila.txt","r")`

Comment: I had it saved as navodila.txt.txt :) The commented part works, thank you, I realized it by writing the full path :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the working directory to be the same as the directory where the script lives.  Here's a technique I use to keep track of relative paths (which revert to the calling path by default).

```
import os
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
with open( os.path.join(script_path,"navodila.txt") , "r") as f:
    do_stuff()
```

This way you just need to have the script and text file in the same directory and it doesn't matter where exactly they are stored in your filesystem or where you are calling the program from.